# calling variable name of a dataframe inside functions in R using "$"

Tags: r, function

I have a dataframe(master) that has some variables which i have stored in the list below:

```
cont<-list("Quantity","Amt_per_qty","Trans_tax","Total_trans_amt")
catg<-list("Gender","Region_code","SubCategory")
```

I am trying to create a function where I can access the variables from dataframe and perform some function on them, though x and val in below function seems to resolve, how can I access the variables using the $ sign inside function

```
univar<-function (x){
                 for (val in cont){
                   print (val)
                   n<-nrow(x$val) }

                      print (n)  }
univar(master)
```

Its returning NULL, I tried even with n<-nrow(x[,val]), that also don't seem to work.

Comment: Use `[[` instead of `$`

Comment: not working either (

Comment: You have a list, you need `c`

Comment: nrow(x) or length(x[[val]])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  i) x[val] returns a data.frame
 ii) x[,val,drop = TRUE] returns a vector
iii) x[[val]] shall return as a vector. Advantage of this is : it also works with data.tables

n <- nrow(x) or length(x[[val]])
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the OP created a `list`, it could be `unlisted` and then use `[`

```
cont <- unlist(cont)
univar<-function(x){
             for (val in cont){
               print (val)
               n<-nrow(x[[val]]) }

                  print (n)  }
univar(master)
```